# Using sqlcmd with FOR XML returns Invalid Object name 'dbo.Table' yet Query runs in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, for-xml

This is my query:

```
SELECT title1, 
    [precinct percent] AS [PrecinctPercent], 
    leader, 
    [leader percent] AS [LeaderPercent], 
    Winner, 
    WinningVotes, 
    leader2, 
    [leader2 percent] AS [Leader2Percent], 
    Loser, 
    LosingVotes 
    FROM [leader].dbo.[RACE]  r inner join
     (select rc.[race number],
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then [candidate num] end) as Winner,
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then Votes end) as WinningVotes,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then [candidate num] end) as Loser,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then Votes end) as LosingVotes
      from (select rc.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by rc.[race number] order by votes desc) as seqnum
            from [leader].dbo.[RACE CANDIDATES] rc
           ) rc
      group by rc.[race number]
     ) rc
     on r.[race number] = rc.[race number]
     FOR XML PATH ('WQAD'), ROOT('root')
```

This query runs and produces some results I desire. I am trying to get the XML file to output as a file. I have been able to accomplish this by opening the xml in Server Management Studio, then running a VB Script to remane the temporary xml file, then move that xml to it's destination. Hey...I gotta do what I gotta do to get these results ON AIR.

Through my travels I have tried to accomlish this using sqlcmd. here is what I am trying to run:

```
sqlcmd -S WQAD-SEVE\SQLEXPRESS -i C:\Users\localtv\Desktop\QUERIES\THISONE22 .sql -o C:\Users\localtv\Desktop\RESULTS236.xml
```

It executes, but when I open/edit the XML file it outputs, I get:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server WQAD-SEVE\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.RACE'.

I have tried inserting [database].dbo.RACE, but still run into the same issue. I have been working on this for weeks now and am trying to figure out a way to get this to work.

Also, when I try to run the command without the -o output destination, the command line echos the same error message. From the look of my query, it makes it through quite a bit before it encounter dbo.RACE.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance for your valued assistance.

***I have removed the [databasename] and .dbo. as well, still Shows RACE as an invalid object.

Comment: When it runs in SSMS, do a select `@@ServerName` - make sure it is `WQAD-SEVE\SQLEXPRESS`?

Comment: I have figured out the issue. I needed to add the -d [databasename] parameter to my sqlcmd, however, it does not kick out a properly formatted xml file. Such as FOR XML PATH.

Comment: +1 I've just repeated on SqlExpress 2008R2. Without `FOR XML PATH` works fine, with `FOR XML PATH` gives invalid object name "table".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've discovered and I confirmed, that you need to specify the `-d MyDatabaseName` option.

Otherwise, you'll get the `invalid object name "Table"` error as soon as you use `FOR XML PATH`, even if you add the database name in your script `FROM` clause (viz. even `FROM Database.dbo.Table` won't circumvent the need for `-d` with `FOR XML AUTO`). Bizarre.

**Re: it does not kick out a properly formatted xml file**:

You need to add the [`:XML ON`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx#sectionToggle7) as the first line in your input (`-i`) file to `sqlcmd`:

```
:XML ON
SELECT title1,
 ...
```

Comment: :XML ON.....Just made my freaking Month! This outputs it as the format I need for my feed. Step 2 of 10 completed!!!  StuartLC....you have saved me a bottle of XANAX! YESSSSS!!!

Comment: +1 I believe this database context problem affects all XML methods (e.g. `FOR XML PATH`) but, like you, I can't explain why that's true (it's like the query is reformulated to explicitly ignore the database prefix on table/view names, and run somewhere else).

Comment: Though, what version of sqlcmd did you reproduce this problem? I couldn't with the 2012 client tools.

Comment: I think it is 2008R2 - will check when I get home later.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but in the SQL Script just add the following before your query:

```
USE dbname;

SELECT ...
```